# What am I supposed to do with the Fliegercorp?

Tags: eastern-front-1941

It's over 30 years old, but [Eastern Front](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eastern_Front_(1941)) (the later produced cartridge version) is still getting a fair bit of playtime in my Atari 800XL.
Playing the Advanced game, you get this new unit: Fliegercorp
How am I supposed to use them? I give them orders, but they don't move.  Is there some trick to it?
No issues using the regular Infantry or Armor units, normally I can kill communists like the 6-string samurai, but this one particular unit just sits there...

Comment: Shooting in the dark here, but the Wikipedia article for the game says " In the highest level, "expert", air force corps (Fliegercorp) are added, and the units can be placed in one of several modes; normal, assault, or defend and move.". Have you tried changing modes?